# Get User Data Google-Play-Games iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play-games, gidsignin

I am using Google-Play-Games for iOS (Objective-C) for my apps. I just want to ask, how to get user data from signed-in user since there's no properties to get user data from GPGManager Class?
When i used sign in method from GIDSignIn Class, the value of [GPGManager sharedInstance].isSignedIn always NO.
Any Solution?

Comment: Can you post part of your code that can be useful to the issue?

Comment: Getting user profile information can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/people) . 
`GIDGoogleUser` contains `GIDProfileData` which has the users `email`, `name`, `hasImage`

Comment: adjuremods, thank you for your information. i just need to add extra scopes to get user information